# How can i avoid NA values when running a specific function

Tags: r

Under R , i developed the following function `Self_mapping` :

The used dataset `Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin` is:

```
library("tidyverse")

L1=list(`2` = c(1, 2, 8, 24, 118, 129, 147, 148, 158, 163, 234, 
298, 347, 352, 419, 520, 555, 657), `4` = c(39, 43, 52, 53, 58, 
62, 63, 67, 71, 85, 98, 100, 103, 123, 149, 221, 229, 261, 328, 
344, 357, 436, 570, 648))

Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin=read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data")
Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin<-Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin[,-1]  
# which(Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin=="?",arr.ind=TRUE)
replace(Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin,Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin=="?",NA)
Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin=type_convert(Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin)
Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin=transform(Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin, X1.3 = as.numeric(X1.3))  # To convert character column to numeric
```

The main function is defined as following :

```
Self_mapping<-function(data_reel , referent_vectors_indices , number_clusters , alpha_init ,sigma_init , sigma_final , T_iter, grid_p=c(n_ligne=10,n_col=8) ){
  
  
  t=1  # initial iterator value
  
  n=nrow(data_reel) #number of rows
  
  list_1= referent_vectors_indices  
  
  referent_vectors_indices=unlist(referent_vectors_indices)
  
  clusterss<-as.matrix(cbind(c(1:n),rep(NA,n)))   # initial_clusters
  
  colnames(clusterss) <- c("obersvations", "clusters")  # columns-names 
  
  K=as.numeric(grid_p[1]*grid_p[2]) #number of neurons
  
  l=number_clusters  # number of excpected clusters
  
  n_centers=length(referent_vectors_indices) #number of centers / initial referent_vectors_indices
  
  d=rep(NA, n_centers)
  
  H_ck=rep(NA, n_centers)
  
  ref_vectors=data_reel[referent_vectors_indices,]  # We subset referent_vectors matrix using input rows indices
  
  w=ref_vectors  
  
  print("referent_vectors : ")
  
  print(ref_vectors)  # we print referent_vectors or w  


  
  r_position = expand.grid(1:grid_p[1], 1:grid_p[2]) # neuronal grid ( cartesian product ) 
  
  sigma=sigma_init
  
  # ordering observations by random to present them for the Som-card
  
  random_rows=c(1:n,sample(x = 1:n ,size = n*T_iter ,replace = TRUE))
  
  
  repeat{
    
    # update alpha and sigma  
    
    alpha=alpha_init*(1-(t/T_iter))
    
    sigma= sigma_init + (t/T_iter)*(sigma_final-sigma_init)  
    
    
    # select one given observation/row indx from "data_reel"
    
    current_row=random_rows[1]
    
    # we compute (BMU) // argmin of d
    
    for( m in c(1:n_centers)){
      
      d[m]=dist(t(na.omit(cbind(data_reel[current_row,],w[m,]))))

    }
    
    c=which.min(d) # indice du classe à distance minimum pour l'observation présenté 
    
    # drop that obervation from the "random_rows" list 
    
    random_rows=random_rows[-1]
    
    #cluster assignment
    
    clusterss[current_row,2]=c
      
    
    #------------ computing H_ck(t) 
    
    for (i in c(1:n_centers)){
      
      # rc and rk grid-coordinates
      
      rc=r_position[c,]
      rk=r_position[current_row,]
      
      # computing H_ck(t) where t is the current iteration    
      
      H_ck[i]=exp(-(dist(t(na.omit(cbind(rc,rk))))^2)/(2*(sigma^2)))

    }
    
      
    R=data_reel[current_row,]   # current presented observation

    #------------ updating referent vectors 
    
for ( j in c(1:n_centers)){
      
      # This is the part that generates NA's
      ref_vectors[j,]=ref_vectors[j,] - alpha * H_ck[j] * (R - ref_vectors[j,])  
      
      max_local= max(abs(ref_vectors[1:j,]))
      
      ref_vectors=ref_vectors/max_local 

      # This is the part that generates NA's
  print(list("indice de l'itération  :"=t,"ref_vectors:"=ref_vectors , "current_j"=j ,"H_ck[j]"=H_ck[j],"R"=R,"ref_vectors[j,]"=ref_vectors[j,]))
      
      
    }
      
    
    #------------ updating referent vectors   
    
    t=t+1     # incrementing current iterator
    
    if( t>T_iter ){
      ll <- lengths(list_1)
      list_2=unname(split(seq(unlist(list_1)), rep(seq(ll), ll)))  
      df=stack(setNames(list_2,1:length(list_1)))
      clusterss = cbind(clusterss , with(df,as.numeric(ind[match(clusterss[,2],values)])))
      return(list(clusterss,ref_vectors))

    }
    
    
  }}



result=Self_mapping(data_reel=Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin[,-10], referent_vectors_indices=L1 , number_clusters=2 , alpha_init=20 , sigma_init=20 , sigma_final=1 , T_iter=2, grid_p=c(n_ligne=698,n_col=9) )
```

This function gives a `data frame` of `NA` values ( within the first iteration ). It's possible to avoid this problem by using `data_reel=na.omit(Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin[,-10])`. However, I'm trying to not remove any of the `dataset` observations.

The same function works as expected with `iris` data ( as well as other datasets without missing values ) :

```
Self_mapping(data_reel=iris[,-5] , referent_vectors_indices=list(c(1,2),c(51,52),c(101)) , number_clusters=3 , alpha_init=20 , sigma_init=20 , sigma_final=1 , T_iter=400, grid_p=c(n_ligne=150,n_col=4) )
```

You could work with a reduced example:

```
g2=Self_mapping(data_reel=Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin[,-10], referent_vectors_indices=list(`2`=c(1,158),`4`=c(39)) , number_clusters=2 , alpha_init=20 , sigma_init=20 , sigma_final=1 , T_iter=2, grid_p=c(n_ligne=698,n_col=9) )
```

After some efforts , I found that the pb is similar to the following :

```
R=structure(list(X5 = 5L, X1 = 4L, X1.1 = 4L, X1.2 = 5L, X2 = 7L, 
               X1.3 = 10, X3 = 3L, X1.4 = 2L, X1.5 = 1L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

ref_vector=structure(list(X5 = NA_real_, X1 = NA_real_, X1.1 = NA_real_, 
               X1.2 = NA_real_, X2 = NA_real_, X1.3 = NA_real_, X3 = NA_real_, 
               X1.4 = NA_real_, X1.5 = NA_real_), row.names = 158L, class = "data.frame")
 

R-ref_vector   # difference of the two vectors :

  X5 X1 X1.1 X1.2 X2 X1.3 X3 X1.4 X1.5
1 NA NA   NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA   NA
```

I hope my question is clear!

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Could someone help plz !

Comment: What would you like to happen when it avoids NA? The examples also seem unnecessarily large to work with. I suggest subsetting it or creating a smaller sample dataset to work with--preferably something that's not outputting too many iterations.

Comment: Also, when I run your `result` command, I am not getting a data frame with NAs. I get `referent_vectors : ` data frame filled with numbers and a 2-by-5 matrix of character values. However, I am also getting an error, "Error in Math.data.frame(ref_vectors[1:j, ]) : non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: X1.3".

Comment: @LC-datascientist : To reproduce the pb , you could work with `g2=Self_mapping(data_reel=Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin_1[,-10], referent_vectors_indices=list(`2`=c(1,158),`4`=c(39)) , number_clusters=2 , alpha_init=20 , sigma_init=20 , sigma_final=1 , T_iter=2, grid_p=c(n_ligne=698,n_col=9) )`

Comment: That gives me an error: Error: unexpected '=' in "g2=Self_mapping(data_reel=Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin_1[,-10], referent_vectors_indices=list(2="

Comment: @LC-datascientist , i updated the post. You have the error because you are assign 2=c(1,158) . you should make 2  and 4 within double quotes ``

Comment: The dataset contains a character column , use `Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin=transform(Breast_Cancer_Wisconsin, X1.3 = as.numeric(X1.3))  # To convert character column to numeric`

Comment: Thanks for updating the post. Now I see NAs in `g2[[1]][,2:3]`. What do you want to do about it though, besides not removing any observations from the dataset? Please clarify the goal you want to achieve, and if you know the part that is creating or leaving the NAs in your `Self_mapping()`, please point it out to us--it'll make it easier for us finding the problem and solution. Lastly, please remove any parts of the function that isn't relevant to the NA output nor vital to the function or question (e.g., the `print(...)` commands and whatever is creating `g2[[2]]`). Keep it simple. Cheers.

Comment: @LC-datascientist, i updated the post. The `print()` is necessary to show the instant where `NA's` their appearing.

Comment: I think now i'm sure of the error origin. consider `max(c(2,NA,5))` : it will return `NA` instead of 5 . So the error is in the instruction `ref_vectors=ref_vectors/max_local `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the error is simply in the instructions :

```
max_local= max(abs(ref_vectors[1:j,]))

ref_vectors=ref_vectors/max_local
```

Consider a simple example :

```
 max(c(2,NA,5))
[1] NA
```

This means we should add :

```
 max(c(2,NA,5),na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 5
```

The solution for the problem is simply to add `na.rm=TRUE` :

```
max_local= max(abs(ref_vectors[1:j,]),na.rm=TRUE)

ref_vectors=ref_vectors/max_local
```